# Why does 'Facebook for websites' login, also log you into facebook.com?

Tags: python, facebook

I am using django-social-auth to login on my website with a facebook login.
This resulted in a problem for me which was as follows.
1. At first login, my website would redirect to facebook login dialog.
2. On correct login details, it would log into my website.
3. Now if I would logout of my website, I would be correctly identified as a guest.
4. But on clicking login with facebook again, I would be directly logged in without facebook dialog box as the previously logged user.

On further research, I realised that when I log into my website with facebook, I would also be logged into facebook.com. And when I logged out of my website, it would only log me out of my website but still maintain the facebook.com logged in. I understood this was the reason that the previously logged in user could simply relogin without needing to enter any username/password.

I understand that this facilitates some user cases. Like if I am already logged into facebook.com and click on facebook login on mysite, I am directly logged in without requiring any username/password details.

The most common solution mentioned on the internet (also available on stackoverflow), is to manually logout of facebook.com using logout redirect or javascript methods. 
But this becomes a problem if the user had manually logged into facebook.com in another tab or if the user is logged into another website using facebook.

What is the possbile reason facebook has implemented 'facebook for websites' in this manner.

One solution that I find partially correct, is to check during login on my website if the login dialog is appearing or not, and based on this data, manually logging out of facebook, if my website caused the login in first place. But this is a partial solution, because it may still logout user out of other sites including facebook, even though he may intend to stay there.
For the time being I will go ahead with this as it seems more in line with what google has implemented across its online apps (gmail, reader, documents, etc.)

But I am still on lookout for a better solution.

The best solution will ofcourse be if we can avoid the facebook.com login during the login process.

Awaiting thoughts and ideas.

Comment: "What is the possible reason" - can you *really* not imagine why Facebook would want to ensure you are logged into their website whenever you use their API?

Comment: This sounds like a roblem with the Facebook API. It should really have an easy way for people to switch user. Talk to Facebook about it!

Comment: They just want the user to be logged in all the time. I think Google is doing the same. And isn't that kind of the point of all these SSO schemes anyway?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I can understand the business aspect of the decision. But I see no technical reason why this needs to be done this way. Trying to confirm the same so that I can do what Emil Vikstrom says.

Answer (score 1):

Not really the core part of your question, but …:

> And when I logged out of my website, it would only log me out of my website but still maintain the facebook.com logged in.

If that’s the case, then you’re doing it **wrong**.

[Facebook’s policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) actually **require** you to provide a button that logs the user out of your site **and** out of Facebook at the same time (see section *I. Features and Functionality*, item *#6*)

Comment: I did see line 6 and that confused me more, since it does not feel right. I should not in charge of logging out of facebook.com . Rather I shouldn't be logged in on facebook.com in the first place.